# Mongodb project Date from numerical value (DateTimeOffset)

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, datetimeoffset

I'm using C# driver to store `DateTimeOffset` field in my collection.
I want to group values by a period of time, ie. by day.

To do so I'm doing something like:

```
db.getCollection('Collection').aggregate([
    {
        $project:
         {
         yearMonthDay: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: { <here should go my DateTimeOffsetField> } } }
         }
    },
    {$group: {_id: '$yearMonthDay', count: {$sum:1}}}
])
```

The problem is that `DateTimeOffset` is stored as `array[2]`, so I cannot use this field to get the date and to format it.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Something like `date:{ $arrayElemAt: [ <array>, <idx> ] }`

Answer (score 0):

So I think I figured out how to do this. `DateTimeOffset` is being stored as an array with two elements: ticks (UTC) and the number of minutes, that are to be added to UTC ticks.

In order to get date from this data, I figured I could store additional field that holds UTC date time and then add minutes from `DateTimeOffset` to this UTC date time.

So I ended up with something like this:

```
db.getCollection('State').aggregate([ {
        $project: {
         yearMonthDay: { $dateToString: { 
             format: "%Y-%m-%d", 
             date: { $add: ["$StateDateUTC",  {$multiply: [ {$arrayElemAt: ["$StateDateLocal",1]}, 60*1000]} ]}
             } },
         ticks: "$StateDurationTicks" }
     },
    {$group: {_id: '$yearMonthDay', count: {$sum:1}, totalTime: {$sum: "$ticks"}}}
])
```

`StateDateUTC` is this additional field that just stores UTC date time.

`StateDateLocal` is `DateTimeOffset` field represented as `array[2]` as I described above.

`StateDurationTicks` is additional duration field that I want to sum up.

`60*1000` converts minutes to milliseconds, because we are adding `Date` and milliseconds in mongo.

Unfortunately, when I used this code directly in mongo c# driver, there's an error about json formatting (a bug maybe?), so we need to rewrite this json in `BsonDocument` form that looks like this:

```
var aggr = collection.Aggregate();
// [...] bunch of Match()
ProjectionDefinition<State> projection = 
    new BsonDocument {
        { "yearMonthDay", new BsonDocument {
            {  "$dateToString", new BsonDocument {
                { "format", dateFormat },
                { "date", new BsonDocument {
                    { "$add", new BsonArray {
                        { "$StateDateUTC" },
                        new BsonDocument { { "$multiply", new BsonArray {
                            { 60*1000 },
                            new BsonDocument { {
                                "$arrayElemAt", new BsonArray{
                                    { "$StateDateLocal" },
                                    { 1 }
                                }
                            } }
                        } } } // multiply 
                    } } // add
                } } // date
            } } // dateToString
        } }, // yearMonthDay
        { "ticks", "$StateDurationTicks" }
    };

var projected = aggr.Project<BsonDocument>(projection);

var groupped = projected.Group(new BsonDocument {  { "_id", "$yearMonthDay" },
                            { "Count", new BsonDocument("$sum", 1) },
                            { "Duration", new BsonDocument("$sum", "$ticks") } });
var bsonList = await groupped.ToListAsync();
```

I think it works.

It looks more like Lisp than C# ;)